# Highcharts in Power BI

Tags: highcharts, powerbi, visualization, reporting, powerbi-embedded

Can we use highcharts in power bi ?
I wanted to use the highcharts visualization in Power BI.
If anyone has tried please provide me with any link or article.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no ready package containing Highcharts for Power BI, and in order to use it, you need to create your own custom `Visual`.

Answer (score -1):

**Reference Link:**
https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Developer/Custom-visual-with-external-library/td-p/275982

You could add a let statement as shown below.

```
let Highcharts = (<any>window).Highcharts;
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate little more about the above statement. If you have tried, can you share some screenshot.

Comment: Just copy pasting links, are not answer.